# autoconf / configure takes long time in cygwin

Tags: makefile

is there a way to speed up the configure script when compiling using the gnu toolchain on cygwin? reconfiguring with only minor changes takes equally long, is there a way to cache the configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duh, there is an option for caching the tests: 
./configure -C